# How to use custom form on add_meta_boxes callback

Tags: hooks, metabox

I am trying to trigger the echo when the form button will click.
but not able to do this. if I don't use form and direct echo there. this is working. but when I use a form, it's not working.

can anyone help me with this?

```php
<?php
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'meta_box_cusotm_buttons' );
function meta_box_cusotm_buttons(){                                      // --- Parameters: ---
    add_meta_box( 
        'sync-with-server-metabox', // ID attribute of metabox
        'Server Action',       // Title of metabox visible to user
        'meta_box_callback', // Function that prints box in wp-admin
        'website',              // Show box for posts, pages, custom, etc.
        'side',            // Where on the page to show the box
        'high' // Priority of box in display order
    );            
}

function meta_box_callback( $post ){

    if(isset($_POST['connectToServer'])){

        echo 'Hello';
        
    }

    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input name="connectToServer" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>

    <?php   
}
```

Comment: What is a final purpose of this button? It's really bad practice to add several submit buttons on a form. Also, post edit page is a huge form already, and you are trying to add a form inside a form. (metabox holds form fields, not forms)

Comment: This is a custom post type where I have few fields.
I need to create a button there on the left side near publish button (I have already created this as you can see on the code) to send the meta box data there with wp_remote_post. this function is working when I directly run the function there. but I want to create a button there. if the admin wishes to send data there then he can click the button to send the data. 

it's more like sync data.

Comment: You don't want to put a form in a form to do that, rather you'll want to bind that button to an AJAX process that executes your PHP for your `wp_remote_post` functionality.  That way the button can be clicked without trigger the actual WordPress edit page form, and you can't since you can't `echo` again in PHP after it's been rendered, you'll also then be able to use AJAX to update whatever it is that needs updating.

Comment: Thank you for the idea.
now I am using ajax :)